# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to edit a record through `AJAX`, but it fails intermittently with the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "/customer/" + customer_id + "/order/" + order_id + "/cust_inline_editing",
    data: {
        '_token': token,
        'order_id': order_id,
        'hourid': hourid
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#inline_submit").text('Update');
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(result.dato);
        var edit_date = result.dato.null.split("-").reverse().join(".");
        $("#dato").val(edit_date);    
    }
});
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: result.dato.null ?

Comment: i have print the value for  alert(result.dato); i got the answers NULL

Comment: No no just i try it result.dato.null   Dhara Parmar

Comment: Actually my code is :

Comment: var result=JSON.parse(data); var edit_date = result.dato.split("-").reverse().join("."); 
    $("#dato").val(edit_date);

Comment: `result.dato` can be `null`.. You need to handle that accordingly! If is is a valid expected value, go with the `STRING.split()`

Comment: Hi  Rayon Dabre  i am trying  STRING.split() but not working

Answer (score 2):

Check condition if result.dato not null then only split.

```
if(result.dato != null) {
    var edit_date = result.dato.split("-").reverse().join("."); 
    $("#dato").val(edit_date);
}
```